# 2d zooming function using transformation matrix

Tags: java, mathematics, matrix, javafx

I'm trying to create a sort of "graphing calculator coordinate system" where you can zoom into a point by scrolling with the mouse wheel. I'm using javafx's transformation matrices (Affines) to keep track of scale and translation. I'm struggeling to come up with a function that allows me to zoom into a point when scrolling, it always comes out weird and moves the canvas in strange ways. This is what I have tried:

```
    double multiplier = event.getDeltaY() / 1000.0; //event.getDeltaY() = mousewheel scroll

    //event.getX() = mouseX, event.getY() = mouseY
    this.cam.move(new Point2D(-event.getX() * multiplier, -event.getY() * multiplier)); //calls Affine.appendTranslation
    this.cam.zoom(1 + multiplier); //calls Affine.appendScale
```

There is also Affine.prependScale and Affine.prependTranslation which adds scale / translation before existing operations. I'm not very good at matrix maths so if anyone knows a working zoom function please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know javafx, but I can tell you the math.

An affine transformation is a linear transformation combined with a translation. e.g.

```m
A(p) = | l11 l12 | * | p_x | + | t_x |
       | l21 l22 |   | p_y |   | t_y |
```

Usually, for simplicity, we use [homogeneous coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousCoordinates.html), which allows to write the transformation as a single matrix product:

```m
       | l11 l12 t_x |   | p_x |
A(p) = | l21 l22 t_y | * | p_y |
       |  0   0   1  |   |  1  |
```

Now suppose that `A(c) = q` and you want to zoom in such that the new transform `A'` keeps `A'(c) = q`.  The linear zoom matrix is trivial:

```m
       | z 0 0 |   | p_x |
Z(p) = | 0 z 0 | * | p_y |
       | 0 0 1 |   |  1  |
```

where `z` is the zoom factor.  Notice that `Z` has one fixed point, `(0, 0)`.

```m
          | z 0 0 |   | 0 |   | z*0 + 0*0  + 0*1 |   | 0 |
Z(0, 0) = | 0 z 0 | * | 0 | = | 0*0 + z*0  + 0*1 | = | 0 |
          | 0 0 1 |   | 1 |   | 0*0 + 0*0  + 1*1 |   | 1 |
```

So basically, you want to combine `A` with a modified version of `Z` such that the fixed point is at `q` (if you place that modified `Z` in front of `A`) or `c` (if you place `A` in front of that modified `Z`).

To have a fixed point at `q`, simply translate so that `q` is sent to `0`, zoom, then translate back.

```m
Z' = T⁻¹ * Z * T
```

where `T` is the relevant translation.  Expanding the matrices, we have:

```m
        | 1 0 q_x |   | z 0 0 |   | 1 0 -q_x |   | p_x |
Z'(p) = | 0 1 q_y | * | 0 z 0 | * | 0 1 -q_y | = | p_y |
        | 0 0  1  |   | 0 0 1 |   | 0 0   1  |   |  1  |
```

Notice that `Z'(q) = q`

Now you simply combine `Z'` with `A`:

```m
A' = Z' * A
```

Now we can see that:

```m
A'(c) = Z'(A(c)) = Z'(q) = q
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully, thank you so much